# Run Cisco VPN in Batch mode

Tags: batch-file, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I have made a bat file to connect to Cisco VPN with a properties file that contains the required parameters and it is working fine.
However,now a new step is added which is enter an OTP received by SMS.
So, the batch file failed to connect as the OTP is not present in the properties file.
Is it possible to block the batch file until i enter the OTP manually ?
below is the batch file code :

```
taskkill -im vpnui.exe -f
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" disconnect
timeout /t 3 /nobreak
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" -s < "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\file3.txt"
timeout /t 3 /nobreak
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this is to wait on user input with the pause command; it's not clear from your question where you want to pause the script, so I can't provide an example however, you can read more about this command here https://ss64.com/nt/pause.html

Comment: the user input is being copied from the properties file, and that last input is the OTP,
So it tries also to read the OTP from the properties file, which is not there, so it fails

Answer (score 0):

This subject is discussed in the post
[PowerShell to automate VPN connection with Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/88321511ce4f416c0605?permalink_comment_id=2897244#gistcomment-2897244).

The post contains a PowerShell script to automate connecting,
but which does not deal with OTP.
The comment by jakawell worked for some users, but I don't have
the environment for testing it myself:

> Love this script. Just sharing something that I did to automate import
> of a one-time password (a la, Google Authenticator, etc.). First, I
> installed this great open-source Python TOTP/HOTP CLI:
> https://github.com/JeNeSuisPasDave/authenticator Once you setup your
> OTP account in that, you can get the latest OTP in your Powershell
> script like this:
>
> ```
> $AuthResult = "foo" | authenticator generate --refresh "once" | Out-String
> $AuthResult -match '([0-9]{6})'
> $AuthCode = $matches[0]
> ```
>
> Just update the authenticator password (foo, above) and update the
> regex to match the number of digits in your OTP (I used a typical 6
> digit code above).

---

*Old answer which does not work for AnyConnect
One Time Password (OTP)*

The batch file can ask for a string, setting a variable to this string,
and then use the variable in the code.

Asking for the variable :

```
set /p "otp=Enter OTP: "
```

Using it can be done in one of the following ways :

```
echo %otp% | command
command -argument %otp%
```

Reference : [set command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Comment: the thing it is asking for the parameter when executing the connect  command
, so what happen it fails then it prompts for the Enter OTP Message

Comment: Is it possible to do the connect twice: The first one will fail, but will send the password, then use it in the next connect command (on condition that the password is still valid on the next connect).

Comment: No,
Each time the OTP is changed

Comment: Does the connect not pause for inputting the OTP?

Comment: Yes it is not pausing, i think it is passing empty value when it prompts for the OTP, so it fails

Comment: Does it pause when run not from inside a batch file?

Comment: you mean copy and paste the bat file commands 1 by 1 ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if it doesn't pause because of the batch file.

Comment: Yes it is not pausing also when exceuting at cmd directly

Comment: I added more information which might help, but I'm limited as I don't use Cisco VPN. You might be able to build on the information I added,

Answer (score 0):

> [image]
>
> ***- So, the batch file failed to connect as the OTP is not present in the properties file.***
>
> ***- Is it possible to block the batch file until I enter the OTP manually ?***
> - No!

There is no blocking the bat file, it is not the bat (batch command sets) which interferes with your need this is a single command:

```
vpncli.exe -s < input_text_file.txt
```

where the vpn cli searches for the information (**all of them**) in your file in text, and not finding (**all of them**), it ends immediately.

There is no way to take your command reading the file's contents to the part where the information is taken care of, to make it wait for missing information, and to continue, change the "interface" and wait for some user to make inputs and transfer to the command in "pause" and then give interpretation of the input to continue the execution.

The next suggestion is:
**1.** use `cisco\vpncli.exe` command with `arguments` but not `< .\input_text.txt`
**2.** double call your bath and use a call in hybrid mode with vbs
**3.** handle the input (VBS 2nd call) to input the sent OPT and return the 1st call
**4.** use the 2nd call with sendkey/VBS to input OPT into the command of the first bat call.
**5.** any difficulty in executing your attempts of items 1-4, return opens a new question